# base64変換した文字列をテキストファイルとしてエクスポートすると再インポートした時、値が一致させる方法がわからない

Tags: python, python3, base64

utf-8形式のテキストファイルへ以下のコードで書き出し、再度インポートを行うとbase64のデータをstring型で保持してしまい、元の変数のデータと一致が取れなくなってしまう。

```
base64.b64encode(string型変数.encode())
```

#### 下記状況

インポートしたテキストの状態 = b'abc'（※string型）
base64.b64encode(string型変数.encode()) = b'abc'（※bytes型）

if文内でインポートしたテキストと変換元のワードが一致するかチェック処理を行いたいが、インポートしたテキストがstring型の状態でbase64時のテキストを保持しており、デコードができない。

**出てくるエラー:**

```
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

エンコード元の変数をインポートした直後の状態に合わせようとするとbyte型からstring変換できません（当たり前）

どのようにすれば一致させることができますか？
また、以下のエラーをなんと解釈するべきかわからないのですが教えていただけますでしょうか。

```
エラーコード'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: インポートしたテキストの状態 = b'abc'（※string型）  の行ですが、bytesっぽい書き方をしているのは書き間違えていませんか? あとstring型じゃなくてstr型ですよね

Comment: 箇条書きの文章とコード断片ではなくてまとまったそのまま動かせるプログラムソースコード/データと実行結果にして提示すれば、他の人も簡単に再現・調査出来るし、回答があった時に自分でも見較べて再試出来るでしょう。

Comment: この辺 [PythonでBase64エンコードとデコード](https://analytics-note.xyz/programming/python-base64/) の記事と、この辺 [16進数文字列とバイト列の相互変換](https://qiita.com/masakielastic/items/21ba9f68ef6c4fd7692d#16%E9%80%B2%E6%95%B0%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%A8%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E7%9B%B8%E4%BA%92%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B) の記事の内容がごっちゃになっているか、あるいはどちらかを知らないか連携のさせ方を知らないとかではありませんか？ そういうのを確認するためにも動かして試せるまとまったソースコードがあった方が良いですね。

Comment: お忙しいところご指摘ありがとうございます。とりあえず解答欄に再現コード・とりあえずの解決方法を残しました。str<>stringについて　すみません丁寧に書いた方がいいかと思ってstringと書いておりますが内部ではstr()で記述できております。お騒がせしてすみません。

Comment: 解決してるようですが, `str(bytes_type_var)` のような扱いがあることは 質問から窺い知ることはできません (問題点はそこ)。スタック・オーバーフローは謎解きサイトでも大喜利サイトでもないので, ほかのコメントにもあるように (質問時に)ソースコード記すようにしたほうがよいでしょう

Comment: インポートしたテキストの状態 = b'abc'（※string型）という**表現だけ**でテキストファイルに b'abc' と6バイト書かれていたという事態を想像させるのは、かなりの難易度の「私はどういうソースを書いたんでしょうかクイズ」でしたね……。これは当てられないです

Answer (score 2):

コメントで御指摘のように質問の仕方には多少なりとも難はありましたが，質問された方がコメントに対応してコードを提供して頂いたので，個人的には pythonによる Base64 処理について改めて学ぶ機会を得ました。

そこで，質問された方の追記の方法を日本語の文字列でも確かめてみたところ，少なくとも私の環境（MacOS 12.6, Terminal(utf-8), Python 3.10.8）では問題なさそうでした。御参考までにコードと出力を転記いたします。

```
import base64

input_str = ('文字列を Base64 エンコードして'
             'テキストファイルに書き込む\n'
             'テキストファイルを読み込み'
             ' Base64 デコードして文字列を取得\n')
print(f'input_str:\n{input_str}')

write_str = base64.b64encode(input_str.encode()).decode()

with open('tmp_base64.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(write_str)

with open('tmp_base64.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_str = f.read()

return_str = base64.b64decode(read_str).decode()
print(f'return_str:\n{return_str}')

print(f'input_str == return_str:\n{input_str == return_str}')
```

```
input_str:
文字列を Base64 エンコードしてテキストファイルに書き込む
テキストファイルを読み込み Base64 デコードして文字列を取得

return_str:
文字列を Base64 エンコードしてテキストファイルに書き込む
テキストファイルを読み込み Base64 デコードして文字列を取得

input_str == return_str:
True
```

Answer (score 0):

色々模索した結果、以下の方法で解決に至りました。
また、未解決部分までの再現コードも書き残します。

```
# text.py
# ※書き出しファイルのディレクトリをCドライブ直下（仮）にしているため、
#   pyファイル実行時にアナコンダプロンプトを管理者権限で実行する前提
import base64

#書き出すテキスト
inputTxt = 'aiueotext'
print(inputTxt , type(inputTxt))
#=> aiueotext <class 'str'>

exportText = base64.b64encode(inputTxt.encode()) #...■１

print(exportText , type(exportText))
#=> b'YWl1ZW90ZXh0' <class 'bytes'>

#書き出し
txtfl = open('C:\\textfile_utf8.txt', 'w')
txtfl.write(str(exportText))
txtfl.close()

#読み込み
readfl = open('C:\\textfile_utf8.txt', 'r')
txt = readfl.read()
readfl.close()

print(txt , type(txt))
#=> b'YWl1ZW90ZXh0' <class 'str'>
#これが型がbytes型とstr型で異なる為、値が同一と判定できなかった


#ここまでが再現コード


#解決方法

# txt と　inputTxt の一致が取りたかったが、
# 以下の記述で読み込みファイル側のデータを何とかエンコードできました。
#base64.b64decode(txt[2:-1].encode()).decode('utf-8')

txt = base64.b64decode(txt[2:-1].encode()).decode('utf-8') #...■２

print(txt , type(txt))
#=> aiueotext <class 'str'>
```

追記：
デコードするときに変数の一部を除外する処理に納得できなかったので調べたところ、
以下のような対応で処理することができました。

```
#修正箇所
#...■１
exportText = base64.b64encode(inputTxt.encode()).decode('utf-8')

#...■２
txt = base64.b64decode(txt.encode()).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

`b'YWl1ZW90ZXh0'`という**長さ12**のデータを

```py
txtfl = open('C:\\textfile_utf8.txt', 'w')
txtfl.write(str(exportText))
txtfl.close()
```

で書き出した時、**15バイトに増えていた**ことに疑問は無かったでしょうか。

ファイルに書かれた `b''`の部分に疑問を感じなかったのでしょうか。

それが本当にbase64でエンコードされたデータの一部だと思っていたのでしょうか。

**そもそもファイルの中身を見たのでしょうか。**

bytes型のデータを書き出すのにテキストモードでファイルを開いて、Pythonでのリテラルを表現する余計なもの(`b''`のこと)が付いた状態で書き出してのが失敗です。

bytes型とstr型の理解がまだのようですのでそのあたりを触ってみるとよさそうですが、それはおいておいて、こうなっていればよかったであろうコードを書いておきます。

```py
import base64

# 書き出すテキスト
inputTxt = 'aiueotext'
print(inputTxt , type(inputTxt))
#=> aiueotext <class 'str'>

# UTF-8でデコードして得たbytes型のデータを、base64でエンコードする
exportText = base64.b64encode(inputTxt.encode())

print(exportText , type(exportText))
#=> b'YWl1ZW90ZXh0' <class 'bytes'>

# バイナリモードで書き出し
binfl = open('textfile_ascii.txt', 'wb')
binfl.write(exportText)
binfl.close()

# バイナリモードで読み込み
readfl = open('textfile_ascii.txt', 'rb')
txt_as_bytes = readfl.read()
readfl.close()

print(txt_as_bytes , type(txt_as_bytes))
# => b'YWl1ZW90ZXh0' <class 'bytes'>

# base64でデコードしたbytes型のデータを、UTF-8でデコードしてstr型を得る
txt = base64.b64decode(txt_as_bytes).decode()

print(txt , type(txt))
# => aiueotext <class 'str'>
```

---

ところで

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode

> Base64 エンコードされた bytes-like object または ASCII 文字列 s をデコードし、デコードされた bytes を返します。

なので読み込みの方は

```py
# ファイルの中身は間違いなくasciiの範囲内なのでエンコーディングの指定が
# UTF-8だろうがasciiだろうがShift-JISだろうが結果は変わらない
readfl = open('textfile_ascii.txt', 'r')
txt_as_str = readfl.read()
readfl.close()

print(txt_as_str , type(txt_as_str))
# => YWl1ZW90ZXh0 <class 'str'>

# base64でデコードしたbytes型のデータを、UTF-8でデコードしてstr型を得る
txt = base64.b64decode(txt_as_bytes).decode()

print(txt , type(txt))
# => aiueotext <class 'str'>
```

でもいいですね。